# My CPU FAN 1 slot on my motherboard got set on fire due to improper seating on from the CPU header

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer

I ended up plugging the 3 hole header onto the last 3 pins instead of the first three which (I'm assuming) caused the fire.

I managed to immediately hit the switch, blow out the solder and reconnect the header onto the CPU FAN 2 slot (correctly this time). When I booted up my computer after everything cooled down it booted up like normally which was surprising. I had no issues like errors or slow boot times. It was like nothing happened.

However I'm still afraid something might happen which will make everything worse like blowing out my GPU or CPU. So I haven't gamed on it (which is what its meant for) or haven't done anything graphically intensive which might increase the voltage. Nothings currently plugged into the CPU FAN 1 slot ( and I'm not going to plug anything in) and I'm torn about what to do. Should I take everything out and RMA it (assuming I have warranty which I'm unsure of) or should I just proceed to do what I normally do.

[image]

[image]

Top left of the RAM right to the block thing on the motherboard.

Comment: If you can do an rma, do it. It may have damaged the cpu fan also.

Answer (score 1):

You already named both options, either RMA or continue to use it. Will you feel troubled and will it nag you? RMA. Would it make sense to RMA? Yes, definitely. After all there should be no reason for this to happen, unless you did something wrong.

Can't RMA and it nags you? Replace the board. Can't RMA and it doesn't? Continue to use it.